# change default format dataExporter in Primefaces 3.5

Tags: pdf, primefaces, datatable, preprocessor

17  ibm07   ASP TEST    131 ABNY    2014-06-19

18  ibm07   ASP TEST    131 BGI 2014-06-19

19  ibm08   ASP PROD    131 VGI 2014-06-19

20  ibm08   ASP PROD    131 BMO 2014-06-19

21  ibm09   SSGA    PROD    131 STST    2014-06-19

22  ibm10   ASP PROD    131 MHTN    2014-06-19

23  ibm10   ASP PROD    131 GTC 2014-06-19

24  ibm10   ASP PROD    131 FTB 2014-06-19

25  ibm10   ASP PROD    131 SUMI    2014-06-19

26  ibm14   ASP TEST    121 LSL 2014-06-19

27  ibm14   ASP TEST    131 LSL 2014-06-19

28  ibm15   ASP PROD    111     2014-06-19

29  ibm15   ASP PROD    111 --- 2014-06-19

30  ibm15   ASP PROD    121     2014-06-19

i would like to change the format of the default primefaces datatable  above 
to the below format.
sorry a don't have enough reputation to post the image!

any one can help please

ibm07    ASP      TEST  111   BBH,BGI,UBSAG,DBCT
   ibm07    ASP      TEST  131   FTB,TRBC,DBCT,LSL,CWT,ABNY,BGI
   ibm08    ASP      PROD  131   VGI,BMO
   ibm09    SSGA     PROD  131   STST
   ibm10    ASP      PROD  131   MHTN,GTC,FTB,SUMI
   ibm14    ASP      TEST  121   LSL
   ibm14    ASP      TEST  131   LSL
   ibm15    ASP      PROD  111   ---

that mean to do a grouping by client to minimaze rows

can any one help me please !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to archieve this using the build-in exporter, I think it's not possible. But you could use a fileDownload Button and create a csv/xls-File in the Controller.

Comment: thnx for replay i will try with the  FileDownload button